# Proving sufficient condition for a differential 1-form to be exact

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, differential-forms, line-integrals

I am really baffled by a seemingly easy question on differential 1-forms.

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $w$ be a differential 1-form on $U$. Suppose $\int_{\phi} w = \int_{\psi} w$ whenever $\phi$ and $\psi$ begin and end at the same points. Show that $w$ is exact.

I don't even know where to start! Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose $\phi$ and $\psi$ are curves in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @JesseMadnick Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good place to start. Choose some $x_0\in U$. Then, given $x\in U$, choose a path $\gamma$ with $$\gamma(0)=x_0,\quad\gamma(1)=x,$$ and set $$F(x):=\int_\gamma w.$$ Buy assumption, $F$ is independent of the choice of $\gamma$. Your job now is to show that $dF=w.$

Comment: I would then expand it out: $F(x) = \int_{0}^{1} w_{\gamma(t)}(\gamma'(t)) dt$? But how does that relate to $dF = w$?

Answer (score 0):

By [Poincaré-Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms#Poincar%C3%A9_lemma) it is enough to show that $w$ is closed, i.e. $d w_x=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Consider without loss of generality $x=0$ and for $E$ a two dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ let $\iota_E\colon E\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be the inclusion. Prove that if $d(\iota_E^*w)_0=0$ for all such $E$, then necessarily $dw_0=0$.
Thus it suffices to consider the case $n=2$. Take balls $B_\epsilon$ around $0\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with radius $\epsilon$, then by Stokes' Theorem
$$
\frac{1}{\pi \epsilon^2}\int_{\partial B_\epsilon} w=\frac{1}{\pi \epsilon^2}\int_{B_\epsilon} dw.
$$
The left integral is $0$ because $\partial B_\epsilon $ is the union of two curves with same start and end point and the right hand side tends to $c$, where $dw_0=c dx\wedge dy$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow0$ (assuming some regularity for $w$, smoothness is more than enough), thus $dw_0=0$.

Comment: I haven't gotten that far yet. I don't know what the lemma and Stokes' theorem is. Any chance we could do it by just using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: Sure, then Amitais suggestion is the way to go. What you're doing there essentially repeats some steps of the proof of Poincaré-Lemma, thus it is not really a different approach. Using the Lemma would just free you of carrying out those technical steps, but since you haven't seen the Lemma yet it is a good idea to approach it directly.